# Will changing my capacitors for ones with higher voltage but same microfarad allow me to use higher voltage batteries

Tags: voltage, capacitor

I have a r/c car that I'd like to use 8 of the 3.2v AA batteries instead of the typical 8 1.2v AA. There are two capacitors one is 2200uf 10v the other is 220uf 16v, if i replace them with 35v of the same capacitance will that work.  Thank you

Comment: I'd be worried about the motor.

Comment: I'd be terrified about the motor. The ESC, too.

Comment: Its not a hobbyist rc its one we carry at RadioShack now. It has the 5 wire control not the digital and i can replace the motor with a better one it has enough room

Comment: Yeah, the electronics might not like that either.  Once you replace the batteries, the motor, and the electronics, you basically have a completely new power system that you might as well plan to buy with all matching specs.

Comment: An explanation of RadioShack's fate.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no. The whole system is engineered to use a particular supply voltage, there's no telling how many different things could go wrong if you overvoltage it by such a great degree (not just by 10% or 20%, by 160%!).

The less simple answer is that it would be possible. With some serious reverse engineering, know-how, and cash for quality parts, you might be able to safely overvoltage a cheap r/c car. Although, you would probably be better off just buying a better r/c car.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what would happen to your RC however, the purpose of capacitor in electronic circuit is to stalilize the voltage and to suply transient current there by rducing the loading of batteries for such transient loads. whether capacitor is 35 volts or 3.2*8=25.6, the charge stored in capacitor is Q=C*V and transient current =Q/t (all approximate). Since motor voltage has increased from 9.6 to 25.6 volts the transient current requirement might increase by 2.5 times.. so if I were to replace the capacitor I would increase the value 2.5 times and voltage 1.5 times 25.4.. This is just highlight the importance of capacitor..For the said RC set up however I would not indulge in any modifications..vtingole